# Converting Integers to Bitmap Color RGB Values C++

Tags: c++, bitmap, rgb

I am trying to replace color in bmp image. I tried making unsigned char variable directly equal to some value... like

`unsigned char oldr=255, oldg=255, oldb=0`

This works pretty fine.

But now I want to take that color as input from the user.
When I use cin stream, it takes 255 as three characters, so directly getting input to unsigned char is not working.
I tried to take input to integer and then typecast to char...
But that is not working. I tried to print the characters and that characters, sometimes, are fine with respect to ASCII table. and sometimes only show spaces. But don't work in bitmap.

```
unsigned int inewr, inewg, inewb, ioldr, ioldg, ioldb // Creating Integers;
cout << "Enter R - G - B of Color to Replace: ";
cin  >> ioldr >> ioldg >> ioldb; // Taking Integers of Old Color From User
cout << "Enter R - G - B of New: ";
cin >> inewr >> inewg >> inewb;  // Taking Integers of New Color From User 
// Type casting to char
unsigned char newr=inewr, newg=inewg, newb=inewb, oldr=ioldr, oldg=ioldr, oldb=ioldb;
cout << newr << " " << newg << " " << newb << endl; // Printing out characters
cout << oldr << " " << oldg << " " << oldb << endl;`
```

And then Checking color and writing in file...

```
for (int j=0; j<height; j++) {
    for (int i=0; i<width*3; i+=3) {
            b = mainarray[i][j];
            g = mainarray[i+1][j]; 
            r = mainarray[i+2][j];
            if ( r==oldr && g==oldg && b==oldb) {
                fout.write((char*) &newb, 1);
                fout.write((char*) &newg, 1);
                fout.write((char*) &newr, 1);
            } else {
                fout.write((char*) &b, 1);
                fout.write((char*) &g, 1);
                fout.write((char*) &r, 1);
            }
        }
    }
```

**Note:** Arrays and all other things are ok in the code that I didn't show you...
Just there is problem in type casting. As I said putting oldr=255 works very fine...
Also I am not using any library. It is for 24-bit bitmap images

Comment: `cout << int(newr) << " " << int(newg) << " " << int(newb) << endl;` would print your variables as integers, so you could at least verify they have expected values.

Answer (score 0):

You're mistaking issues with outputting characters for problems with inputting them.  Simply `cin >> my_unsigned_char` works just fine: the user types 255 and that value is stored in `my_unsigned_char`.  The apparent problem is in...

```
cout << newr << " " << newg << " " << newb << endl; // Printing out characters
```

When the values are `unsigned_char` this sees values like 255 and sends them to the terminal as individual characters, rather than displaying the numeric value as a series of characters representing the individual digits in decimal, i.e. '2', then '5', then '5'.

Summarily, you can input directly to `unsigned char`, but should then cast to `(int)` while outputting if you want to read the numeric value entered:

```
std::cout << static_cast<int>(my_unsigned_char) << '\n';
```

Answer (score 0):

first: I see some error in the code:

there is missing ";" after ioldb

```
unsigned int inewr, inewg, inewb, ioldr, ioldg, ioldb // Creating Integers;
```

the "oldg=ioldr" must be  "oldg=ioldg"

```
// Type casting to char
unsigned char newr=inewr, newg=inewg, newb=inewb, oldr=ioldr, oldg=ioldr, oldb=ioldb;
```

there is more "`" in the end.

```
cout << oldr << " " << oldg << " " << oldb << endl;`
```

if you you want to checke the value you cin, I think you need to cout as following, it's more clear:

```
cout << static_cast<unsigned int>(newr) << " " << static_cast<unsigned int>(newg) << " " << static_cast<unsigned int>(newb) << endl; // Printing out characters
cout << static_cast<unsigned int>(oldr) << " " << static_cast<unsigned int>(oldg) << " " << static_cast<unsigned int>(oldb) << endl;
```

And can you more detail about the fault about "don't work in bitmap", and I think the fout must be initialized by "std::ofstream::binary"